# jQuery - want to RESTOREDefault on a form submission

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I am submitting a form via ajax and using event.preventDefault() to stop forwarding to the action url. It subsequently shows a confirmation window with the result of the form submission. How would I ensure I could submit the form however many times again?

Comment: ... you can submit it as many times as you like. i guess i don't quite understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

On your form submit, disable the submit button. In the success callback from your AJAX, enable the button again to signify that the form has went through and you are able to receive another form.

Comment: you could also add an image like a loading.gif that you show on submit click and then hide on success.